# XNA - scripting on XBOX?

Tags: ironpython, xbox360, xna-4.0

I've incorporated IronPython into my XNA game on Windows, but, of course, that won't work on the compact framework since the DLR stuff isn't available.

Are there any scripting object implementations available that will work with the compact framework? It's really convenient to be able to tweak the system real-time without having to recompile.

Comment: Edit and Continue can tweak plain C# code while it runs. Admittedly you have to pause in the debugger first...

Answer (score 1):

Most things in IronRuby will work on the compact framework (it runs on Windows Phone today).  You may need to deploy the DLR yourself but because it's just an additional library it is possible to run it.  IronPython could be made to work but it'll require some work to avoid doing code generation where it does today which is not possible on the compact framework.

Comment: IIRC DLR uses a lot of reflection stuff which is unavailable on .NETCF on the 360. IronRuby works on WinPhone because its needs are supported by the framework there, but it'll have the same problem as IronPython on the 360.